# ZF Curl - How to set custom header when it is not allowed in the adapter

Tags: curl, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have a Zend\Http\Client with a Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl and want to set a custom header to the adapter. But in the curl adapter there is an array called `invalidOverwritableCurlOptions` which includes the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. So it is impossible for me to set that header.

Is there another way to set it?

```
$adapter = new Curl();
$client = new Client();

$adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'AuthenticationToken:123456'
]);

$client->setAdapter($adapter);
```

If I comment out the line, where the curl options get validated, everything works fine...

```
// set additional curl options
if (isset($this->config['curloptions'])) {
    foreach ((array) $this->config['curloptions'] as $k => $v) {
        //if (! in_array($k, $this->invalidOverwritableCurlOptions)) {
            if (curl_setopt($this->curl, $k, $v) == false) {
                throw new AdapterException\RuntimeException(sprintf(
                    'Unknown or erroreous cURL option "%s" set',
                    $k
                ));
            }
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok i got it. You can set headers dirctly to the client.

```
$client->setHeaders([
    'AuthenticationToken:123456'
]);
```